# How to handle COM settings in Virtual Serial Driver

Tags: driver, umdf

I have created virtual serial driver (UMDF) using microsoft sample. Instead of device, i am just receive and forward data to TCP server.

Do i need to handle virtual COM settings like Baud rate, Parity, Stop Bits, Data Length(set by application) in the driver considering that it is just virtual and no device? What about flow control as well?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples

Using UMDF and basically a combination of these two example drivers from the WDK:

- src\serial\VirtualSerial
- src\general\echo\umdfSocketEcho\Driver

i.e. The driver device creates a `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` device interface,
implements all the serial IOCTLs (from the `VirtualSerial` example), and then
forwards all IO read/write requests to a TCP/IP socket file handle (from the
`umdfSocketEcho` example).